# sending mail in web2py

Tags: email, web2py, yahoo

I'm trying to send a mail in web2py but nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
from gluon.tools import Mail
mail = Mail()

def sendMail():
    mail.settings.server = 'smtp.yahoo.com:465'
    mail.settings.sender = 'mymail@yahoo.com'
    mail.settings.login  = 'abc:password'
    mail.send(to='a@gmail.com', subject='Hello', message='You've received a mail.')
```

Does anyone have any ideea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running your application on localhost?

Comment: @GauravKalyan no, I'm not

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your `mail.send` to:

```
 mail.send(to='a@gmail.com', subject='Hello', message="You've received a mail.")
```

It seems like a simple `SyntaxError`, because you're defining your `message` string with a single quote, and you're using a single quote at **You've**, which is making `message='You' and the rest (ve received a mail....) a SyntaxError and using double quotes should fix it.